# Simple priority queue in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue

can anyone tell me an easy way to implement a priority queue that only offers extract_min, add, and reduce key without using the build-in one in Java. It is better to be as efficient as possible and not hard to implement. Please give me a sample. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I smell homework, because otherwise you should use Java PriorityQueue. If you don't want to put effort into making any inroads on your problem, why do you expect us to?

Comment: So what class at what college is this for?

Comment: hehe, yes, but this is only a part of my assignment. The main part is done

Comment: i wish homework questions were banned. they very rarely want the technically `best` solutions.

Comment: That's all good, but even so, we are not here to hand you code if you just have a broad question that shows zero effort on your part.

Comment: How about telling us what you've done so far? Code samples would help.

Comment: Can you just give me some hints then? because only extract_min, add, and reduce key are needed, the data structure can be simplified

Comment: I can provide the code sample, but it is really irrelevant to this question. I used the build-in priority queue, and just got informed that I cannot use it...

Comment: Ok, why don't you try writing it and come back for some help if it doesn't work.  You haven't explained what reduce does?

Comment: How would you implement a queue, the only difference is that instead of adding to the end, you add in order of priority. I suggest you try a simple queue first and go from there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/priority-queue

Answer (score 3):

It's rather conceptual problem than implementational one, so I suggest you to have a look at wiki [Priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) or [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) pages or dive into some really great books, for instance "Introduction to algorithms". When you understand logic behind those data structures (and other algorithms as well) implementing them in any programming language shouldn't be a big deal.